# What does "Mutually Comparable" mean?

Tags: java, collections, comparable

I read that :

> whenever a collection need to be sorted, the elements must be
>   mutually comparable.

I wrote the below code and it worked correctly. Can you please tell how class b and class c are mutually comparable and what is the meaning of being "mutually comparable"?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class b implements Comparable<c> {
    String str1;

    b(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }

    public int compareTo(c object) {
        return str1.compareTo(object.str1);
    }
}

class c implements Comparable<b> {
    String str1;

    c(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }

    public int compareTo(b object) {
        return str1.compareTo(object.str1);
    }
}

public class a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b obj1 = new b("monster");
        c obj2 = new c("aman");

        ArrayList list  = new ArrayList();
        list.add(obj1);
        list.add(obj2);
        System.out.println("unsorted list = "+list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("sorted list = "+list);
    }
}
```

Comment: It simply means that every element can be compared to every other, using some sort of "stable" compare function.

Comment: Furthermore, if `A > B` and `B > C`, it must be true that `A > C`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for classes `A` and `B` to be mutually comparable, these requirements need to be satisfied:

- A call of `compareTo` on an instance of `A` passing an instance of `B` must be allowed
- A call of `compareTo` on an instance of `B` passing an instance of `A` must be allowed
- If `a.compareTo(b)` returns `x`, then `b.compareTo(a)` **must** return a value `y` with the opposite sign, or zero, when `x` is zero.

The classes in your code are not mutually comparable, because an attempt to pass an instance of `c` to `b`'s `compareTo` (and vice versa) works fine. However, they are not comparable to instances of their own classes, which would create a problem if you were to add more items to the collection to be sorted.

In order for the container to be sortable, your class needs to be comparable to instances of its own type as well.

Comment: But class b and class c are mutually comparable, that's why the code is running correctly

Comment: @user3519914 Take a look at [what happens when you try adding more items to the collection to be sorted](http://ideone.com/OaWOB5).

Comment: I am highly impressed by the code but sir i am unable to understand why the error is actually coming?

Comment: understood the reason sir, thanks for highlighting the point.

Comment: @user3519914 This is your code, with two changes: I added two more instances to the collection, and renamed class `A` to `Main`, as part of requirements of the `ideone.com` site. The error that you see comes from the code the compiler generated to cast `object` to `b` and `c` behind the scene.

Comment: so will sorting does it check all the 3 conditions foe every two instances?

Comment: @user3519914 Sorting is done in a very smart way, so it's hard to say how many comparisons exactly it would perform. When you sort four items, three is the lower bound; there may be more. Also, it's not necessary that each object would be compared to each of the remaining ones, because `sort` relies upon transitivity of comparisons (i.e. if `a<b` and `b<c`, `sort` would simply assume that `a<c` without performing an additional check).

Answer (score 3):

Mutually comparable means that instances of both classes must be comparable to the other.

In case of type `A` and type `B`:

- `A` must implement `Comparable<T>` where `T` extends `B` (or is `B`)
- `B` must implement `Comparable<U>` where `U` extends `A` (or is `A`)
- The comparison must be consistent. Consistent means that if `a>b` then it must be so `b<a`. And if `a<b` then it must be so `b>a`. And if `a==b` then it must be so `b==a`.

So that the following code can be written:

```
A a = ...;
B b = ...;

int rab = a.compareTo(b);  // A is comparable to B
int rba = b.compareTo(a);  // B is comparable to A

// And also consistent:
if (   !(rab<0 && rba>0)
    || !(rab>0 && rba<0)
    || !(rab==0 && rba!=0))
    System.out.println("Not consistent!");
```

If type `A` and type `B` are the same, then `a` and `b` are obviously mutually comparable.

Sorting algorithms usually require the elements to be mutually comparable so they can compare any 2 of the sortable elements to each other.

**Back to your question**

Your case is special. Your 2 objects `obj1` and `obj2` are mutually comparable according to the definition. Your `obj1` and `obj2` **instances** are mutually comparable, but your `b` and `c` **classes** are not.

However, if you would pass another instance of either type `a` or type `b`, all elements would be not. Because if we would select 2 instances from the collection of the same type, they would not implement `Comparable` to the same type.

```
obj1.compareTo(obj2); // This is valid, b implements Comparable<c>
obj2.compareTo(obj1); // This is also valid, c implements Comparable<b>

obj1.compareTo(obj1); // This is NOT valid! b does not implement Comparable<b>
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to collections, so can you please explain the meaning of <? extends B>.

Comment: Edited to clarify it.

Comment: so according to you my classes b and c are mutually comparable or not ?

Comment: Your `obj1` and `obj2` **instances** are mutually comparable, but your `b` and `c` **classes** are not. See edited answer.

Comment: so will sorting does it check all the 3 conditions foe every two instances?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the sorting algorithm. But most likely no.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works *only by chance* and it has so many mistakes that they cancel out each other resulting into working code.

1. You use [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html): `ArrayList list  = new ArrayList();` [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)
2. If a class implements `Comparable<T>`, `T` should be a super type of that class. For example `Integer implements Comparable<Number>` would be just as fine.

> the elements must be mutually comparable

That means that *each element from that collection must be comparable to each other* and in your case that works only because you added only 2 elements (adding more would result into ClassCastException at runtime).

If you want a sortable collection containing both `B` and `C`, find common parent of those classes (or perhaps create an interface for it, lets call it `BC`) then you would go:

```
class B implments BC, Comparable<BC> { ... }
class C implments BC, Comparable<BC> { ... }
```

and changle your list declaration and creation to: `ArrayList<BC> list = new ArrayList<>();`

**EDIT:**

To truly guarantee that `ArrayList<BC>` is sortable, we need to change the `BC`'s declaration to:

```
 interface BC extends Comparable<BC> { }
```

Otherwise we could have `class D implements BC` *but not* `Comparable<BC>`. With this new annotation we say "anything that implements `BC` must implement `Comparable<BC>` as well".

Now you can write only

```
class B implments BC { ... }
class C implments BC { ... }
```

(Also note that you can add `getString()` method to interface `BC` to avoid the `instanceof` testing and casting in the compare method)

Comment: sorry sir i know this code has many mistakes but i had to write it like this to make it work.

Comment: No problem. In most cases, you only have `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>` and then `ArrayList<Foo>`. The *mutually comparable* simply means that `foo` can be compared to another `foo`.

Comment: sir i tried it the correct way by implementing BC but my code doesn't work. Can you please tell the necessary corrections http://ideone.com/mpvzLj

Comment: True the original solution wouldn't work, thanks for noticing. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It means that for any two items in the collection, you must be able to compare A to B and vice versa.